# Azure pipeline - trigger on PR creation and on merge

Tags: azure-pipelines

Setting up CI/CD for our project.

We want the pipeline to work as follows -

On PR creation to Main -
Builds(can’t merge PR if fail)
Run Unit Tests

After merge PR - pipeline
Builds - block if fail
Unit tests(once there) - block if fail
Deploy to test
Automation runs once deployed, won’t block

On push to branches
Builds
Unit tests

I have to go through a whole process before I can get a pipeline tested and confirmed so just wanted to check with the smart people of stack overflow I am on the right track as quite new to azure.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'  # Trigger on every push to any branch

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master  # Trigger on PRs targeting the master branch
    
below here is code to build and test
```

```
trigger:
  -master

below here is code to build, test, deploy and automation
```

Am I understanding it right? Should these triggers cover off all the triggers I have specified above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically trigger pipeline on PR build in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76602610/how-to-automatically-trigger-pipeline-on-pr-build-in-azure-devops) The `pr` section is only for GitHub and Bitbucket. Please refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I understanding it right? Should these triggers cover off all the triggers I have specified above?

You are on the right direction, I add more details as below, hope it's helpful.

1. [YAML PR triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines#remarks) are supported **only** in GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud. If you use `Azure Repos Git`, you can configure a [branch policy for build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies#build-validation) to trigger your build pipeline for validation in PR.
2. > After merge PR - pipeline Builds - block if fail Unit tests(once there) - block if fail Deploy to test Automation runs once deployed, won’t block

If you would like to build pipeline **after** PR merge, you can set `CI trigger` as you did.

By default, a job or stage runs if it doesn't depend on any other job or stage, or if all of the jobs or stages it depends on have `completed` and `succeeded`.  If you would like to `unblock` some jobs/tasks if previous step is failed, you can use [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages).

In addition, you can `ignore` the error in some tasks with [continueOnError:true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cstages#how-can-i-trigger-a-job-if-a-previous-job-succeeded-with-issues), which can also continue to run the next task.

It's recommended to check the official docs and links inside for more details:

[Specify events that trigger pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Okay cool so for build and unit test on pipeline creation use branch policy.

For the rest use yaml as I have.

One final question - for the build and test on push and the build, test, deploy automation, do I need to have two separate yml files?

Comment: Yes, if you already have build and test in branch policy, you can put the deployment in a new pipeline(new yaml), you can publish the files in 1st pipeline(build&test), and download the artifact in deployment pipeline,  it can reduce duplicate jobs.